# Action bar menu item not working in fragment

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, fragment

I am working on a navigation drawer in which i am using multiple fragment .In one of the fragment i have to use menu item for some action .Now i can inflate menu item on action bar on that fragment but action is not performing .

```
 public class Location extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Fragment fragment;
    Button arrived_mbtn;
    TextView current_mtv,request_mtv;
    LinearLayout btn_mlayout,journey_mlayout;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
       return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("you are in oncreate", "dfsdfsd");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        try {

            if (fragment != null) {

                fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.interrupted();
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_card_detail,menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

by this code an item is inflate on action bar but on click it did,t show any thing .

Answer (score 0):

Change like this. You have not called show() on toast.

```
case R.id.action_settings:
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Once check your R.menu.menu_payment_card_detail.xml file. In that action_settings menu id is there??

Comment: if it display on action bar ..it means it is there ..but it is not clickable

Comment: It is displaying on action bar means the menu item is there with some id...but it is not necessary to have action_setting only. May be some other id is there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81170/discussion-between-deep-singh-and-chandrakanth).

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreateOptionsMenu method as below.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_card_detail,menu);
    }
```

And whatever id you have applied to your menu item, use that in the condition to check whether that menu item is clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

- Move the `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the `onCreateView()` method;
- Use `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_card_detail,menu);` in the
  `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Something like this:

```
@Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_card_detail,menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }
```

- Add the show() method to your Toast `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0):

In fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // set setHasOptionsMenu 
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score -2):

Check the parent activity doesn't eat the item selected, i.e. make sure if the parent activity implements `onOptionsItemSelected()` that it returns false for your fragment's items.